# Result of rollsum needed in final row of each set

Tags: r, zoo

I'm using `zoo::rollsum()` to get the sum of an observation with the two immediately preceding it. However, currently, the result is showing in the top/earliest row of each set of three, but I want it in the final/latest row.

This is example code:

```
library(zoo)
library(data.table)
random_dt <- data.table(group = LETTERS, total = sample(1:10, 26, replace = T))
random_dt <- random_dt[, .(group, total, 
                       rolling_total = as.numeric(rollsum(total, 3, align = "right")))]
```

I am using `align = "right"`, as you can see, which is what I understood affected this. When I use `align = "left"` or `align = "center"`, nothing changes, however.

I also get a warning, which could possibly be relevant:

> Warning message:
>   In as.data.table.list(jval) :
>     Item 3 is of size 24 but maximum size is 26 (recycled leaving a remainder of 2 items)

I understand the message - by doing this, the first two observations don't have enough previous observations to create a rolling sum of three. Ideally these values would be left as NA or something. But possibly this issue is contributing to the values being pushed up, as it were? It isn't obvious to me what the final two values in the `rolling_total` column are based on.

Comment: Please check `?rollsum` `na.pad = FALSE`, by default.  If there are NA elements at the beginning, could be removed.  Change it to `na.pad - TRUE` i.e. `random_dt[, .(group, total, rolling_total = as.numeric(rollsum(total, 3, align = "right", na.pad = TRUE)))]`

Comment: Thanks for commenting, akrun. The help for `rollsum` says `na.pad` is deprecated. I saw that but didn't really understand what `na.pad` was meant to do anyway. However, I've now followed that trail further and used `fill = NA`, and that gives me the two first values as NA, while shifting the other values down as needed. Thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry David, I thought it existed in base R but it turns out it is from the `zoo` package. I included the data.table information because I am not very familiar with data.tables and I thought it could be relevant information. I have edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `na.pad` is by default `FALSE`, and the `fill` argument is not specified.  So, it would drop the `NA`s at the beginning and this causes imbalance in the length.  Change it to `na.pad = TRUE` and should work

```
random_dt[, .(group, total, rolling_total = as.numeric(rollsum(total, 3, 
     align = "right", na.pad = TRUE)))]
```

Also, the OP mentioned about deprecated warning for `na.pad`, thus `fill = NA` would be more appropriate